# Magento2 Update price automatically when quantity changed on product page?

Tags: magento-2.1

**How to Update price automatically when quantity changed on the product page?**

I am updating the qty input type to dropdown through below code and I want when I change the qty in dropdown price to be updated...

```
 <td class="col qty" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')); ?>">
       <div class="field qty">
                <select id="cart-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo $_item->getId() ?>-qty" name="cart[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')); ?>" data - cart - item -
                        id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        echo $_item->getSku() ?>">
                    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $qty; $i++): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"<?php if ($i == $block->getQty()) {
                            echo 'selected';
                        } ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                        <//?php $i = $i + 4; ?>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
```

Comment: it mean discount  or any else?

Comment: No i added + and - button in quantity so i want to update price when quantity increase and decreases so help meregards

Comment: @sangan, post your code, so that we will find answers from that.

Comment: still i did't updated ..just i made qty input type as dropdown so then whenever we select qty price to be update..??